# Validate DecimalRangeField in Flask's WTForms

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to validate a `DecimalRangeField` so that the user is required to provide input. The problem is that I want a default value of for instance 50 (slider appears in the middle), which leads the build-in validators `DataRequired` and `InputRequired` (I tried both) to fail because they take the default value as the given score even if the user didn't show any action (at least this is what I think happens).

How can I have some default value but still check if the user took any action (clicking somewhere on the slider even if it is the same value as the default in the end) and display an error such as "This field is required" in case the user didn't touch the slider? Do I need a custom validator for this?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Here are the relevant code parts:

**index.py**

```
@app.route("/questionnaire1", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def controlAndDeliberation():
    form = controlAndDeliberationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for())
    return render_template('control_and_deliberation.html', form=form)
```

**questionnaires.py**

```
class controlAndDeliberationForm(FlaskForm):
    perceivedControlQ1 = DecimalRangeField(
                        '1. How much control did you feel you have?',
                        default=50,
                        validators=[DataRequired()]
                        )
```

**control_and_deliberation.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.perceivedControlQ1.label }}<br>
    {{ form.perceivedControlQ1 }}
    {% for error in form.perceivedControlQ1.errors %}
        <span style="color: #d60000; font-size: 15px">{{ error }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have to best handled on the front end (unless somebody shows up to correct me here).
You can use Javascript to prevent form submission and display a message until the user clicks the slider.
Otherwise you would have to reject a certain value and reload the page and flash an error message telling the user to move the slider away from '50'. The issue here that because it is a slider, the user doesn't have to provide input, it always sends a numerical value on form submit.

Comment: Thanks for the evaluation Kevin. Unfortunately I lack experience with Javascript, do you have any tip how to do this or where to start?

Comment: Two tips on how to do this 1) forget about making the user click the slider first and focus on the backend, or 2) if you want to make your page more dynamic try learning some Javascript and maybe jQuery. If you are comfortable with Python and HTML, you will pick it up very quickly. Take a look at the html and .js file here if you wanna see how to do this https://repl.it/@KevinWelch/LightcoralEnergeticModel